# Is there a way to make an onpress navigation inside a result of a array map in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a simple array of names in `this.state.members`. I used the map function to iterate the members.
I want to add a button for each member so, when i click to them, i go to a screen dedicated to each member. 
I test the button outise the loop, it is working.
But for those inside the map function, its says "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation')
onPress"
i spent a whole day trying to understand what is going on without any luck.
Any help will be appreciated.
Here is my code

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { ListItem, Button } from "react-native-elements";

export default class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
 static navigationOptions = {
   header: null
 };

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     members: ["Allie", "Gator", "Lizzie"],
     id_groupe: "",
     groupe: ""
   };

   // this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }
 render() {
   const members = this.state.members;
   const namesList = members.map(function(name, i) {
     return (
       <Button
         onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}

         title={name}
         key={i}
       />
     );
   });

   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <View>{namesList}</View>
       <View>
         <Button
           title="Back to home"
           onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
         />
       </View>
     </View>
   );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: "#fff",
   alignItems: "center",
   justifyContent: "center"
 }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use an arrow function, and you will not have the `this` issue. But not sure about your actual problem, if the arrow function works let's check if you have any other issue.
Arrow function when you iterate with map:

```
const namesList = members.map((name, i) => {
     return (
       <Button
         onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
         title={name}
         key={i}
       />
     );
   });
```